# In spaCy, how do I keep proper nouns together when parsing a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm using spaCy 2.3.2 and Python 3.8.  I would like to parse a sentence and keep proper nouns together.  I can use the following code just to extract proper nouns ...

```
doc = nlp("Jill laughed at John Johnson.")

entity_types = ((ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents)
print(tabulate(entity_types, headers=['Entity', 'Entity Type']))
print()
```

which produces

```
Entity        Entity Type
------------  -------------
Jill          PERSON
John Johnson  PERSON
```

And then I can use this to extract all tokens in my sentence ...

```
token_entity_info = ((token.text, token.ent_iob_, token.ent_type_,) for token in doc)
print(tabulate(token_entity_info, headers=['Token', 'IOB Annotation', 'Entity Type']))
```

which produces ...

```
Token    IOB Annotation    Entity Type
-------  ----------------  -------------
Jill     B                 PERSON
laughed  O
at       O
John     B                 PERSON
Johnson  I                 PERSON
```

but how do I combine or modify the above so that I can have

```
Token
--------
Jill
laughed
at
John Johnson
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  In particular, we have no idea what your undefined functions do.  I use the Stanford package, which already keeps noun phrases together.

Comment: @Prune The example code here is completely adequate for what they're trying to do, they have done nothing wrong.

Comment: @polm23 I think what Prune is asking is about the import and initialization for `nlp` and `tabulate` function. It might be standard for those familiar with the tools, but still needed for exact MRE nonetheless.

Comment: I guess it's technically necessary for an MRE, but spaCy has a very consistent initialization process for the `nlp` object and the behavior of `tabulate` is not relevant to the question. I don't think a numpy question would be criticized for omitting `import numpy as np`.

Comment: The definitions are, indeed, the missing part.  `nlp` is hardly a unique name.  For those who know *only* the packages that OP is using, this may be clear; as a future search item on Stack Overflow, it needs the missing context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to merge named entities. You can use the `merge_entities` pipeline component. From [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities):

```
texts = [t.text for t in nlp("I like David Bowie")]
assert texts == ["I", "like", "David", "Bowie"]

merge_ents = nlp.create_pipe("merge_entities")
nlp.add_pipe(merge_ents)

texts = [t.text for t in nlp("I like David Bowie")]
assert texts == ["I", "like", "David Bowie"]
```